# requiring a class caused double execution

Tags: ruby

I defined a class in a separated file and required it and created an object.but it seems that initialize function executes twice.

a.rb:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/*.rb"].each do |f| require(f) end
object = First.new
```

b.rb ( which is required):

```
class First
  def initialize
    p "Hello"
  end
end
```

and result:

```
"Hello"
"Hello"
```

and it gets funnier if I say I tested something else. I put b.rb codes in a.rb( I mean I defined First class in a.rb) and the result was same:

a.rb:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/*.rb"].each do |f| require(f) end #I now this line is useless

class Second
  def initialize
    p "Hello"
  end
end
object = Second.new



 "Hello"
 "Hello"
```

**but when I removed the first line(requiring code)(which was useless in second test(because we defined the class in a.rb and so b.rb got useless)) everything was ok**:

a.rb:

```
#Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/*.rb"].each do |f| require(f) end #now it is not executed.


class Second
  def initialize
    p "Hello"
  end
end
object = Second.new

"Hello"
```

any idea?!

Comment: Because you includes `a.rb` and executes it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just require the file you need rather than all .rb files in that path? If you change

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/*.rb"].each do |f| require(f) end
```

to

```
require 'b.rb'
```

It should work as expected

The thing is that you will at the very least be including both a and b rb files and that is possibly where the problem lies

It is also possible that you have another .rb file in that folder that also sends "Hello" as output when initialised.

Remember that your require is including ALL rb files in that folder. i.e the result of `ls *.rb`

Comment: I know but I'm curious about the reason.I'm requiring b.rb which I have nothing to do with but it affects my result.(second test) Why? And test, by changing the first line to what you suggested problem gets solved.